# Restkit Response with UTF8 chars

Tags: ios, json, restkit, non-ascii-characters

I successfully post and receive data by using RestKit.
For example, I can easily decode this response (it is the debug output from RestLog):

```
 response.body={
    "response":
      {"fields":{"name":"test"}}
    }
```

But when the data contains accents, the response is encoded weardly:

```
response.body={
"response":
  {"fields":{"name":"\u00c3\u00a8\u00c3\u00a8"}}
}
```

and then my mapping is wrong.
The mapping is done as usual:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *fields;
```

I extract the `fields` from the response and then do the mapping.

```
 mappingDict = @{  @"fields"       :@"fields" };
 responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SynchObj class]];
 [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDict];
```

How to handle accents?

Comment: How are you mapping (what to)? The accents are just part of the string so should be constrained to string processing after the mapping has completed.

Comment: So what, specifically, is wrong. The dictionary is not set? Or the string inside is corrupted somehow? How are you using the dictionary contents?

Comment: What is wrong is the coding: there is a way to handle escaped chars or I have to change the remote WS?

Comment: If the original string is UTF-16 or something then you just need to know the encoding. Strings will usually be assumed to be UTF-8 and should just work when displayed. If escaping has been applied at the server then you need to explicitly de-escape before you use it (after mapping).